# How to create a Unity script for drag and drop in 3D Scene

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to create a script that works to drag and drop an object in the 3D. So the script should be able to change the position of the object in X axis, Y axis and Z axis. I found something and changed it a little bit but it does not work how I want it to work. Here is my code. How should I approach this to solve this problem?

```
using System.Collections;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using UnityEngine;



public class DragAndDrop : MonoBehaviour

{
bool rayCast;
private Vector3 mOffset;
RaycastHit modelobject;
private float mZCoord;
private void Start()
{

}
private void Update()
{

  /*  if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, out modelobject, 20f))
    {
        if (modelobject.collider.gameObject.name == this.gameObject.name)
        {
            Debug.Log("Piece has been found");
            if (Mathf.Approximately(modelobject.transform.position.x, this.gameObject.transform.position.x) && Mathf.Approximately(modelobject.transform.position.y, this.gameObject.transform.position.y))
            {
                Debug.Log("Found");
       //         this.gameObject.AddComponent<Drag>();
                this.enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }*/
}

void OnMouseDown()
{


    mZCoord = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(

        gameObject.transform.position).z;



    // Store offset = gameobject world pos - mouse world pos

    mOffset = gameObject.transform.position - GetMouseAsWorldPoint();


}



private Vector3 GetMouseAsWorldPoint()

{
    // Pixel coordinates of mouse (x,y)

    Vector3 mousePoint = Input.mousePosition;



    // z coordinate of game object on screen

    mousePoint.z = mZCoord;



    // Convert it to world points

    return Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePoint);
}



void OnMouseDrag()

{

    transform.position = GetMouseAsWorldPoint() + mOffset;


}
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if (collision.collider.name == this.gameObject.name)
    {
        Debug.Log("Correct");
        this.gameObject.transform.position = collision.collider.gameObject.transform.position;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Hi! We need some clarification. Are you trying to do this in the editor (scene view) or while playing the game (game view)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will struggle to be able to move across all three axis at once. You will likely need to take a similar approach to what unity does and have arrow handlers on the x y and z axis to drag each axis individually. Otherwise it will be very difficult to implement the third axis of depth in your controls. The only way I can see this being done all at once is to use the scroll wheel to manually increment or decrement the third axis.

Comment: Thus, I've changed the positions z positions of the object and made them stabile, now I only use X and Y. Thank you anyway.